# How do I prevent text alignment across divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment

I have the code:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #888;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prevent Text Alignment</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>I have this text and it continues on this many lines.</div>
  <div>I have this other text on this other div and this other div continues on more lines, so it is higher.</div>
  <div>You can see that the bottom of each paragraph is aligned with the others.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you click "Run Code Snippet", you can see the three `div`s have the bottom of their text aligned.  What I want is that the `div`s stay normally aligned, not caring about the other `div`s' text positions, like these empty cards:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #888;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Prevent Text Alignment</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <p>As you can see, without text they are not mis-aligned (because then the bottom of the text is still the same).</p>
</body>

</html>
```

A CSS or JS answer would be fine, although I think CSS can not detect how many lines are taken.  The reason CSS is there is because there might be some CSS property to stop this text alignment.

**Important Notes:**

I can't have static positioning because on someone's device it might take 3 lines and on someone else's it might take 4.  It needs to dynamic position it.

To help some people, I was thinking maybe use `element.getBoundingClientRect().y`.  That's the distance between the top of the page and the top of `element`.

It would be preferred to:

1. Not include external libraries
2. Be cross-browser
3. Be short (under 10 lines)

*None of these are forced, it's just I would like to avoid them*

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: don't overthink it: vertical-align:top and you are good

Comment: @TemaniAfif & person/people who marked this as a duplicate: Thank you for showing me this wonderful answer!  I will certainly use this for my `div`s. 